# Prevent line break for 2 divs inside other div

Tags: html, css, dojo

Would like to achieve something like this:

```
|--- parent-div ------------------------|
||----- child-div-1 -------||----- child-div-2 -------|
|---------------------------------------|
```

Which in fact will look like:

```
|--- parent-div ------------------------|
||----- child-div-1 -------||----- chi..|
|---------------------------------------|
```

Imagine that you have an input field that shows user's domain relatively to the website's name e.g. `http://www.domain-name.com/**username**`

- Parent div has to stays fixed size e.g. 200px;
- Child div 1 and 2 float next to each other

What happens now is Child Div 2 jumps into next line:

```
|--- parent-div ------------------------|
||----- child-div-1 -------|            |
||----- child-div-2 ----------|         |
|---------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Well description. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks! 'white-space: nowrap' and 'display:inline-block' solution was the best in my case, since both domain and user names can have different widths.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve this:

```
|--- parent-div ------------------------|
||----- child-div-1 -------||----- child-div-2 -------|
|---------------------------------------|
```

- Use `white-space: nowrap` on the parent to allow its children to punch out of it
- Give the children `display: inline-block`
- You can show the ellipsis on a long url with: `text-overflow:ellipsis` and `overflow: hidden`

### Example

This example scrolls the overflow. To hide it, place `overflow-x: hidden` on the parent. To show it, remove the overflow property.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
      <a>http://www.example.com/this-is-really-long/</a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
      <a>http://www.example.com/this-is-really-long/</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I went with this solution since it allow maximum flexibility in my case.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks, it would work using just white-space: nowrap; in a parent and display: inline-block; in children

Answer (score 3):

You can use float concept to achieve this. For a better understanding, you can use widths initially.

For parent div use: 100%;
For child divs use: 50% , 50% (total can be max of 100%)

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/ybt5tc8b/2/) of the below:

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 1 content comes here.
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2 content comes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this concept - it is clean. Unfortunately in my case both domain and user names very their width.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a `float:left` to those child divs, for example:

```
child-div-1, child-div-2 {
    float:left;
}
```

and you have to give a specific width to the `parent-div`:

```
parent-div {
    width: 200px; // you can choose whatever you want
}
```

Comment: What if div1 takes 80% of the width? and div2 requires 30%

Comment: You can give `overflow-x:hidden;` to the parent.

Comment: Well!! there can be a number of solutions. We doesn't know what op has tried?

Answer (score 1):

you could try using the CSS property `display: inline-block;` for both inner div's, That should align them up next to eachother.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2kg6qhL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">    
  </div>
  <div class="child-div">    
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent-div {
  width: 200px;
  background: #F00;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child-div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0F0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2rkmxmhh/) for reference.